# Styling TextBox in WPF generates Storyboard errors

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I have found a nice style for WPF applications and I´m trying to make it work with ValidationErrors.

Here the full textbox style:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" />
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13.333" />
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBackgroundBrush}" />
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorderBrush}" />
<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30" />
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,4" />
<Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxFocusedBrush}" />
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
      <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxHoverBorderBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxHoverBackgroundBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" />
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadOnlyVisualElement" />
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
          </VisualStateGroup>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" />
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" />
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
          </VisualStateGroup>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Valid" />
            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                  </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                  </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                  </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
          </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Opacity="1">
          <Grid>
            <Border x:Name="ReadOnlyVisualElement" Background="{StaticResource TextBoxReadOnlyBackgroundBrush}" Opacity="0" />
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
          </Grid>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" BorderBrush="{StaticResource DisabledVisualElement}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource DisabledVisualElement}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" />
        <Border x:Name="FocusVisualElement" BorderBrush="{StaticResource TextBoxFocusedBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" />
        <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ValidationErrorElement}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Visibility="Collapsed">
          <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}">
              <ToolTip.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                  <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
              </ToolTip.Triggers>
            </ToolTip>
          </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        </Border>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

The problem is when it will show the validation error, it says that the element "validationTooltip" cannot be found.
I've tried change the storyboard from

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
```

to

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=validationTooltip}">
```

and the error has stopped, but instead another error shows, saying "cannot resolve all property references in the property path" pointing to "IsOpen".

Do you guys have any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I got the expected result using triggers and creating my own style.
Here is the code.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="FieldTextBoxStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource FieldTextBoxStyle2}">
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
      <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Opacity="1">
          <Grid>
            <Border x:Name="ReadOnlyVisualElement" Background="{StaticResource TextBoxReadOnlyBackgroundBrush}" Opacity="0" />
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
          </Grid>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" BorderBrush="{StaticResource DisabledVisualElement}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource DisabledVisualElement}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" />
        <Border x:Name="FocusVisualElement" BorderBrush="{StaticResource TextBoxFocusedBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" />
        <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ValidationErrorElement}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Visibility="Collapsed">
          <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" IsHitTestVisible="true" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}"/>
          </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        </Border>
      </Grid>
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        <MultiTrigger>
          <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true" />
          </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
          <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxHoverBorderBrush}" />
          <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxHoverBackgroundBrush}" />
        </MultiTrigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
          <Setter TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="true">
          <Setter TargetName="ReadOnlyVisualElement" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
          <Setter TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
        </Trigger>

        <MultiTrigger>
          <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="true" />
            <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true" />
          </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
          <Setter TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
          <Setter TargetName="validationTooltip" Property="IsOpen" Value="true" />
        </MultiTrigger>

        <MultiTrigger>
          <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="false" />
            <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true" />
          </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
          <Setter TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </MultiTrigger>

      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```